# How to animate my clouds going in different directions in CSS?

Tags: css, css-animations

Hey guys I am trying to animate my two clouds going in different direction from each other at different speeds from off screen back to on screen repeatedly. I sort of have an animation going on with one cloud but for some reason it won't work with the other cloud or I should say how I do not want it to work. Is there anyone who can please help me?

Here's my CSS

```
/*My clouds positions*/
 img.cloud1 {
 float:  right;
 animation: pulse 3s ease infinite alternate, 
 nudge 10s linear infinite alternate;

  }

 @keyframes nudge {
 0%, 100% {
 transform: translate(0, 0);
 }

 50% {
 transform: translate(1100px, 0);
 }

 80% {
 transform: translate(-150px, 0);
 }
 }


 img.cloud2 {
 float:  left;


  }
```

Comment: Please make your code into a working snippet. As things stand at the moment we don’t know what pulse does, if it sets a transform you may have trouble with nudge, and the second cloud has no animation attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the animation 'path' within the keyframes. You then assign it with the animation property, where you can make a bunch of variations such as: duration, iteration, delay, direction (you can reverse it) and probably the most interesting for your clouds is animation-timing-function where you can create custom 'bezier' which is basically a property where you can define the speed in much detail.

[image]

I suggest you take a look here to learn more: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

Or be a bit more specific with your question on how it should work and add a 'working' example

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look.